# How to find and replace file values while reusing parts of the values?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I want to change thousands of hard coded CSS pixel values to a variable that re-uses the value, such that if the value is `height: 100px;` then the new value would be `height: calc(100px / var(--resoRatio);`. And I need to account for lines that contain 'px' multiple times.

```
For each line
   for each 'px'
       move to the left until either a ':', ',' or ' ' (space) is identified
       select the remaining value along with 'px' starting from first detected colon, comma or space
       store selection in variable X
       replace content after ':' with 'calc(X / var(--resoRatio))'
```

Could this be done with Visual Studio Code find and replace with regex?

Comment: As per my understanding what you can do is in Visual Studio Code select the value which you want to replace (in your case 'height: 100px;' )  and press ctrl + shift + L it will select all the matched values and then you can placed with new values.

Comment: It would work if all the values were 100px, however in this case, the number before the px would be different per case. So I want to use the number in front of each px, and re-use it in a variable, that I replace it with.

Comment: It's hard to do that in just one go but you can try like select ''px; or 'px' and press ctrl + shift + L and then press right arrow key then ctrl + shift + left arrow key it will select whole value. e.g. 10px, 100px, 1000px

Comment: As I've 12,000+ such values to change across many files, I'm looking for a programmatic approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a regex search for

```
height:\s*(\d+px)
```

if you have fractionally sizes (100.3px) use

```
height:\s*([\d.]+px)
```

replace with

```
height: calc($1 / var(--resoRatio))
```

**Edit**

If you want generic attributes you can apply multiple times use

Search

```
(\w+)\s*:\s*(\d+px)
```

replace with

```
$1: calc($2 / var(--resoRatio))
```

Comment: Nice! Perfect, and although I was going for a generic version (not height specific), I saw the logic of it and by just removing 'height:' and inserting a space in front, ' \s*(\d+px)' I was able to get what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: @danefondo By adding an additional capture group you can capture the attribute too, now you can apply the search-replace an additional time

Comment: Wow! Thank you! That's super cool!!

Comment: Is there a filter that could be created to avoid some attributes, such as 'border-radius'

Comment: replace the `(\w+)` with `(height|width)`, and any other attribute, but this will hit `max-height`, maybe start each attribute on a new line and use `^\s*(height|width)`